# When is logistic regression minimizing under squared error loss the same as maximizing binomial likelihood?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, optimization

Implementing logistic regression and getting different results depending on whether I minimize squared error or maximize log likelihood.  When are the two equivalent?

Comment: @Sycorax this seems like a special case of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317613/why-are-the-least-squares-and-maximum-likelihood-methods-of-regression-not-equiv